# How do I add a template specialization when for a generic method on a generic class when the two types are equal?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to add in a specialization where the generic type of method and class agree, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to specify the template instantiation (if it is even possible).

My best guess would be something like the following (though it obviously doesn't compile):

```cpp
template<typename ClassT>
class Foo
{
public:
  ClassT x;

  template<typename MethodT>
  void Bar(MethodT arg)
  {
  }
};

template<typename T>
template<>
void Foo<T>::Bar(T arg)
{
  x = arg;
}
```

Comment: Does this have to be a specialization or would a regular overload do?

Comment: Unfortunately, a template class must be specialized before any of its template methods can be specialized.

Comment: chris if an overload works, that would be great, but I don't think it'd be possible to do without enumerating each type, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is usually the case when considering function template specialization, an overload can handle it:

```
template<typename MethodT>
void Bar(MethodT arg)
{
}

void Bar(ClassT arg)
{
  x = arg;
}
```

When you call `Bar`, one of the candidates will be a function template specialization and one won't. Think of the class template as stamping out real, concrete member functions where possible when it's instantiated. There's a rule pretty late in overload resolution to prefer the one that isn't a function template specialization if it's a tie up to that point.

What you end up with is the second overload being called when there's an "exact match" in types (which allows for a difference in top-level `const`). If exact matches are too narrow, you can restrict the first overload to widen the second:

```
// Allow the other overload to win in cases like Foo<int>{}.Bar(0.0).
// std::enable_if works as well before C++20.
template<typename MethodT>
void Bar(MethodT arg) requires (not std::convertible_to<MethodT, ClassT>)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, it's not possible to do this with template specialization. However, something similar can be accomplished by using std::enable_if_t and

```cpp
template<typename ClassT>
class Foo
{
public:
  ClassT x;

  template<typename MethodT,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<ClassT, MethodT>::value>>
  void Bar(MethodT arg)
  {
  }

  void Bar(ClassT arg)
  {
    x = arg;
  }
};
```

`std::enable_if_t` will only return a valid type when the input type arg is true. Therefore, the template substitution will fail when `MethodT` and `ClassT` are the same type, but the non-template overload will not fail. The template substitution failure is ok under SFINAE.